# how to insert from different inputs

Tags: c#, .net, sql, database, t-sql

i am trying to insert different `values` into a table from my database , i retrieve these values from different `tables` , input from `textBox` in Windows form etc ..

but the syntax of my query is not correct , i want to know if there is a possiblity to insert these inputs in one query :

```
     String query4 = @"INSERT INTO FACFIN 
(Nom_pren_RS,trimestre,exercice,Nb_factures,Prix_total_HT) 
    values 
        ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "', 
    SELECT cast(count(trimestre) AS varchar(6)) AS Nb_factures FROM facture
     WHERE 
    (facture.Nom_pren_RS='" + textBox1.Text + "'),
SELECT cast(SUM (cast(Prix_vente_HT AS BIGINT ))AS varchar(15)) 
from facture 
where (facture.Nom_pren_RS='" + textBox1.Text + "')    )  ";
```

i know that there is a risk of sql injection and i know that i have to use parameters but i just wanted to test the code to see if it does insert , the syntax of the insert is probably wrong

- the `nb_factures` it should be `varchar(6)` so i casted it
- the column `Prix_vente_HT` in table `facture` is `varchar` so i casted it
  to `BIGINT` to    execute the SUM and then casted the SUM to varchar
  because the `Prix_total_HT` should be `varchar` in the table **FACFIN**

Comment: You say the syntax is not correct.  What happened when you ran it?  Also, you might be better off developing the syntax in management studio with static values where you plan to use variables.

Comment: this error is displayed :System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a select statement to a values list, instead this select statement keeps your aggrigates but brings the text box values into a single select statement.  If you need to pull rows from multiple tables you can also do a UNION on the select section.

```
String query4 = @"INSERT INTO FACFIN (Nom_pren_RS,trimestre,exercice,Nb_factures,Prix_total_HT) 
SELECT '" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "', cast(count(trimestre) AS varchar(6)) AS Nb_factures ,
cast(SUM (cast(Prix_vente_HT AS BIGINT ))AS varchar(15)) as Prix_total_HT
FROM facture
WHERE (facture.Nom_pren_RS='" + textBox1.Text + "')";
```

The result would look something like this to SQL Server

```
INSERT INTO FACFIN (Nom_pren_RS,trimestre,exercice,Nb_factures,Prix_total_HT) 
SELECT 
    'TEXT_BOX_1_VALUE','TEXT_BOX_3_VALUE','TEXT_BOX_2_VALUE', 
    cast(count(trimestre) AS varchar(6)) AS Nb_factures, cast(SUM (cast(Prix_vente_HT AS BIGINT ))AS varchar(15)) as Prix_total_HT
FROM facture WHERE (facture.Nom_pren_RS='TEXT_BOX_1_VALUE')
```

Comment: In case this isn't clear, don't use the values keyword.  Use select instead.

Comment: thanks that worked , i was looking for this syntax to see if it's possible to use it :)